# How are displays updated?

Tags: lcd, oled

If you would excuse the infiltration by a curious computer scientist with very little knowledge of hardware, I would like to understand better how modern displays are updated.

I don't care about HDMI or VGA or whatever, I'm curious about the LCD or OLED panel itself, the layer below HDMI.

Does it have it's own RAM representing 24 bits of color per pixel? And if this is the case does one just update this RAM and the display (errr) "controller" (correctly term?) scan through the ram updating the display at whatever the refresh rate is?

Or does the panel's controller *pull* data from some other area?

Comment: you're basically right about the "RAM addresses"; that's the basic idea. setting a low-level hardware register's value will change the shown pixel on the next refresh.

Comment: There's a lot more to it than this  https://www.fairchildsemi.com/applications/home-entertainment/led-tv-monitor/blockdiagram-1.html

Comment: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9393.pdf 
 
There's a lot more to it than this

Comment: The pixel memory is the LCD pixel.  The video processor converts the data in selected format to raster scan the LCD at the frame refresh rate

Answer (score 2):

A typical computer monitor, while it does have ram does use it for displaying, lacks a frame buffer and expects the input source to constantly refresh the data it is displaying.

The pc or whatever sends a screen full of information, which the display stores in memory then updates the frame. At which point the pc sends the next frame. At a given refresh rate.